# Deploying a C++ application developed on Mac OS in a Ubuntu environment

Tags: c++, makefile

I have developed a small web server based on Crow, [link](https://github.com/ipkn/crow). 
I'm pretty new to developing in C++ so all advices are greatly appreciated. 
I'm developing the application on my Mac and intend to deploy it to a Ubuntu server. 
I use Make to build the application so that I can run it on the Mac. The application is depending on two libraries, pqxx and png++. None of those are installed on the server.

I'd like to know how to run this application on the Ubuntu server. Mainly I guess the issue is, can I make a specific build on the Mac that is targeted for running on the Ubuntu server? Or do I have to build the application on the server?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are several ways this can be done. Lookup e.g. cross compiling.

Comment: If the libraries are available on Ubuntu, you should install their -dev packages and then compile your code on the target machine. On my Debian I see `libpqxx-dev` and `libpng++-dev`, maybe they are the same for Ubuntu.

Comment: The easiest approach is to transfer all the source code to Ubuntu machine and compile on it.

Comment: bear in mind that anything your program does that not strictly standard may require some attention. clang (OSX default) is a lot more permissive than recent gcc (the default on ubuntu). You may have to add in some system header includes that you didn't need to on OSX, also capturing `this` in a lambda in a template class requires more explicit expression in gcc.

Comment: Mac and Ubuntu are all UNIX-LIKE systems. If I were you, I would work on Mac immediately and deploy the project on Ubuntu. If there is something different, I use `#ifdef` to control the different version.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I will get going trying to build on the target system.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to install Ubuntu on a VM on your Mac and deploy there your application.
Less easy solution: move source files on server, deploy the application, delete the sources from server.

Theoretically, both system are linux, so as long as you are using standard c++ libraries the code should run anyway.

In any case, the dependencies on Linux and Mac for Crown are different, so (most probabily) you have to install some libraries on your server.

Comment: Thank you. A great suggestion.